# Bezout's theorem for finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

I would like to know if the following statements holds:

Suppose $K$ is a finite field. Is it true then that for any two polynomials $f,g\in K[x,y]$ that have no common factors, the number of solutions of $f(x,y)=g(x,y)=0$ is at most $\deg(f)\times \deg(g)$?

I know a proof of this statement when $K$ is infinite, but I don't see how to adapt it to the case when $K$ is finite.

By the way, is it true that if $K$ is finite, $f,g\in K[x,y]$ and $f$ and $g$ have a common factor over an algebraic closure of $K$, then $f$ and $g$ also have a common factor over $K$?

---

Peoples who voted to close the question, could you please answer the question at least? The comment left by Daniel Lourghan doesn't answer this question. Indeed, why, when you pass to $\bar k$ it can not happen that suddenly $f$ and $g$ have a common factor? (By the way, this is what I have already asked above...)

Comment: The version given as a equality for plane projective curves is almost always stated and proved over an arbitrary algebraically closed field (e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem). The version you want (upper bound) then trivially holds over an arbitrary field $k$, since the number of solutions over $k$ is less than or equal to the number of solutions over $\bar{k}$.

Comment: It does not look very true as stated. Say $f=x$ and $g=y$.... Don't you want $f=0=g$ instead??

Comment: Daniel Loughran, if you say this is trivial, could you explain then why when you pass to $\bar k$ the polynomials still don't have a common factor? You agree that if polynomials have a common factor over $\bar k$, the number of solutions will be infinite, so your argument will break?

Comment: The existence of a common factor is computed using the resultant, which can be computed over any division ring which contains the coefficients. See my lecture notes for more: https://github.com/Ben-McKay/concrete-algebra/blob/master/algebra.pdf

Comment: Sorry Ben, are you speaking about common factors of polynomials of two variables? In your notes as far as I can see you speak about resultants of polynomials in one variable? However here we are dealing with two variables...

Comment: If your polynomials have a common factor $h$, they are also divisible by ${}^{\sigma }h$ for each $\sigma $ in $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{K}/K) $. It follows easily that they have a common factor in $K[x,y]$.

Comment: (@abx is, I think, [also](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351066/bezouts-theorem-for-finite-fields#comment879892_351066) using implicitly the existence of a unique monic gcd, so that Galois is not just permuting around common divisors but actually fixing the greatest.)

Comment: Dear abx, thanks for the comment. This answers the question indeed.